# Determining which monitor the cursor is in via AutoHotKey. Monitor bottom value is wrong

Tags: windows, autohotkey, multiple-monitors, mouse-cursor

I want to be able to determine which monitor the cursor is in. Ideally this would be a dynamic solution for any number/configuration of monitors.

I thought it would be simple to just read the boundaries of each monitor and test if the cursor is within said boundaries.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen
GetMonitorMouse()
{
    MouseGetPos, x, y

    SysGet, Mon1, Monitor, 1
    SysGet, Mon2, Monitor, 2
    SysGet, Mon3, Monitor, 3

    if(x >= Mon1Left && x <= Mon1Right && y >= Mon1Bottom && y <= Mon1Top)
    {
        TrayTip,,monitor1, 1, 16
        SetTimer, TurnOffTrayTip, 500
    }
    else if(x >= Mon2Left && x <= Mon2Right && y >= Mon2Bottom && y <= Mon2Top)
    {
        TrayTip,,monitor2, 1, 16
        SetTimer, TurnOffTrayTip, 500
    }
    else if(x >= Mon3Left && x <= Mon3Right && y >= Mon3Bottom && y <= Mon3Top)
    {
        TrayTip,,monitor3, 1, 16
        SetTimer, TurnOffTrayTip, 500
    }
    else
    {
        TrayTip,,monitor unknown %x%-%y%, 1, 16
        SetTimer, TurnOffTrayTip, 500
        SplashTextOn, 400, 300, CursorMonitor, monitor unknown %x%-%y% # %Mon1top% ~ %Mon1Bottom% $ %Mon1Left% ~ %Mon1Right% 
    }

 sleep, 3000
 GetMonitorMouse()

}

GetMonitorMouse()

TurnOffTrayTip:
TrayTip
return
```

However, I don't understand the boundaries returned by SysGet. The bottom boundary appears arbritrary. For example, `Mon1Bottom` is `-8`, and Mon2Bottom is `352`.

Below is an image showing the layout of my three monitors as Windows sees it. In green, I show the boundaries that SysGet returns (top,bottom,left,right). In red, I show the actual dimensions of the display.

[image: Monitor Layout]

I don't know how to test which monitor my cursor is in. Does anyone know how I can fix my script? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: Just something I noticed without digging too deep yet: in the picture it appears the green dimensions might be swapped for monitors 2 and 3. So it may also be that the monitor number that `SysGet` retrieves doesn't necessarily match Windows display settings.

Comment: Which monitor is your main display in Windows? Based on your picture and my above comment, I'm guessing that it's #2.

Comment: @EvanElrod - My main display is number 1. And yes, it seems 2 and 3 are swapped. But I'm still confused as to what those numbers even mean. If monitor 2's Y is from 0 to 1080, then why is Monitor 1 from -1088 to -8? This whole thing hurts my head because the cursor position is measured from the bottom left corner, yet the monitors measure from the top left corner.

Comment: I believe the cursor position is also measured from the top-left corner - at least it shows that way with Window Spy.

Comment: If mon1 is your main display, then I think the green dimensions for #3 are for #1, #1 are for #2, and #2 are for #3. I think I might have an answer for you in a bit when I'm home and can devote some time to it.

Comment: @EvanElrod - You're right; The Y origin for the cursor is also in the top-left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that your script is fine. Based on the above comments, here is a more accurate depiction of your setup.

[image: Monitor Setup]

So, I think it just comes down to, 'why is monitor 2's bottom edge Y-8?' I think it may have been accidentally placed this way. To fix it, I would try the following:

1. move monitor 3 off in space;
2. move monitor 2 up and away, then reposition it directly above monitor 1 (as was probably initially intended);
3. finally, reposition monitor 3 so that its top edge is in-line with monitor 2's top edge.

Now, as far as the monitor names from `SysGet`, they may or may not match how it's identified in Windows display settings. I think you'll just need to determine which monitor is which with testing first and proceed with that.

Comment: Great, so it wasn't as bad as I thought it was. Turns out I needed to swap the Top and Bottom values in the conditional (because the origin is at the top). That's why it always ran the last `else`. (Unknown monitor). As for knowing which monitor is which, that may not be necessary.

Comment: OK, now I'm curious about the 8 pixels Y coordinates between monitor 1 and monitor 2. Why doesn't m2 start from 0 or -1 ?  I don't see the issue with the X coordinates between m1 and m3. Any idea?

Comment: @Yane I think normally it would, but it may have been placed like this accidentally. Perhaps m3 was placed before m2 and m2 was placed such that it snapped to the top edge of m3 instead of m1. As m3 may have been extremely close to the desired location (only 8 px off), it may have gone unnoticed until now that it was off at all.